# Woocommerce show only the variation price

Tags: woocommerce

Normally woocommerce shows the minimum variation price at the top and at the bottom there is the variation price that changes depending on the option you have selected in the drop down list. This means i have 2 prices one at the top and one at the bottom.

Is it possible to have only one price? I want to keep the bottom price but i want to show it at the top. I want to replace the minimum variation price at the top with the changing one located at the bottom.

Thanks

Comment: It might help to show a picture of some sort here if you can.

Comment: See this pic. There is a "from price" at the top which is the minimum variation price and another one at the bottom that changes every time you make a selection from the droplist. I just want to keep the latter and place it at the top.

http://kb.oboxsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/woocomvariation_done2.png

Comment: As pointed out by @bazinga in a deleted answer, it seems though that these answers work for some people: [How to display variable prices by default in woocommerce?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117418/how-to-display-variable-prices-by-default-in-woocommerce) and [How To Customize Position of »add to cart« of WooCommerce on Product Page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/114734).